# Change Solr base context path

Tags: apache, solr, jetty

I've installed a Solr (5.3.1 and 5.5.0) in a Ubuntu machine.

With apache I've made a

```
ProxyPass /MySolr http://{url}:8984/solr

ProxyPassReverse /MySolr http://{url}:8984/solr
```

So, when I load {url}/MySolr the Dashboard doesn't load because one json.

`http://{url}/solr/admin/cores?wt=json&indexInfo=false&_=...`

That's normal because the correct URL to load would be:

`http://{url}/MySolr/admin/cores?wt=json&indexInfo=false&_=...`

When i see the other resouces, solr get the correct URL like:

`http://{url}/MySolr/js/scripts/segments.js?_=5.5.0`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process will not work because probably this json is specified with absolute path. In this case Solr doesn't know your mapping. If you want to change the context path you need to change this configuration on Jetty. This way solr will start using the new context.
The first step is create a symbolic link `MySolr` pointing to `solr` directory (default located in `$SOLR_INSTALL_DIR/server/`).
Now change the Jetty configuration file `$SOLR_INSTALL_DIR/server/contexts/solr-jetty-context.xml` to point to the new context path like this:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath"><Property name="hostContext" default="/MySolr"/></Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.base"/>/solr-webapp/webapp</Set>
  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.base"/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
  <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

Now just restart Solr to be able to access using the new base context path.

Comment: It Works!! Really Thanks!!

Comment: At which level you create the symbolic link  ? $SOLR_INSTALL_DIR/server/MySolr -> $SOLR_INSTALL_DIR/server/solr ?

Comment: @GéraldReinhart have you tried to do it without the symbolic link?

Comment: I found another solution.  Playing with jetty.home and jetty.base settings we managed to deploy 2 different instances based on the the same solr installation. On each instance we can define the url context. :

    jetty.home is solr distribution itself
    jetty.base define the specific setting of an instance : solr-jetty-context.xml

see https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/startup-base-and-home.html