# Solr hostcontext is not working in 6.0.1

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 6.0.1 and it is installed in Windows server. When I am trying to change the default  hostcontextfrom /solr to /search, Solr is not working properly.

Example:
http://localhost:9290/solr to http://localhost:9290/search

It is not loading the cores which we have already.

I have tried as given in this link but no luck.
[Change Solr base context path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059747/change-solr-base-context-path)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change both **solr-jetty-context.xml** and **jetty.xml**. However, the new Admin UI will still not support it, as per [SOLR-9000](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9000).

Comment: Thanks Alexandre !